# Facebook Deep Linking in Android in a Game with Two Package Names

Tags: android, facebook

I am currently working on an Android game that we will be offering for download on both the Google Play and Amazon app stores. In order to do this, each version uses a separate package name (for the sake of completeness, they are of the format com.companyname.google.gamename and com.companyname.amazon.gamename).

The game also uses the Facebook SDK to allow users to send requests to one another and uses deep linking to allow users to launch the app by tapping a notification in the (native Android) Facebook app.

All of the deep linking and related Facebook functionality works fine, however we have encountered a problem getting both the Google Play and Amazon versions of the app working, namely that the Facebook App Setup page only allows us to list one package name for the app. As a result, the only option I can see at this point is to add separate facebook apps for each version but if we do this, users who downloaded the Amazon version of the game will not be able to send notifications to those that bought the Google Play version, and vice versa, which isn't ideal.

Does anyone with any experience of a similar situation have any suggestions for alternative approaches?

(Please note - I have read a number of similar posts on SO about offering a free a paid version of an app where the advice is to merge them into the same package name, but I don't believe that is possible here).

Answer (score 0):

I've finally managed to clarify this issue - there is no way at present to list more than one package name for an Android app as part of the Facebook app setup. As a result, the *only way* to use Facebook deep linking in an Android app is to ensure that all versions of your app use the same package name.